# Spring data elasticsearch : serialize joda time

Tags: java, jodatime, spring-data-elasticsearch

I am using elasticsearchTemplate.index() to index documents into elasticsearch server. Following is the part of my document:

```
    @Field(type = FieldType.Date, format = DateFormat.basic_date, index = FieldIndex.not_analyzed)
    private Date date;
```

While saving the document, the date gets saved in long format (with miliseconds) which is the expected behavior.
Now, in the same document, I want to add created and modified timestamps with JodaTime type. Following are the timestamps:

```
    @JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ")
    @Field(type = FieldType.Date, format = DateFormat.basic_date, index = FieldIndex.not_analyzed)
    private DateTime createdDateTime;

    @JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ")
    @Field(type = FieldType.Date, format = DateFormat.basic_date, index = FieldIndex.not_analyzed)
    private DateTime modifiedDateTime;
```

Now, when I save the document, these 2 are stored as complex objects (having components like monthOfYear, dayOfMonth, hourOfDay etc). However, I want these fields to be stored like date field (i.e. long timestamp). which changed should I make?

I have tried defining ObjectMapper with jodaModule as a bean in my app but it doesn't seem to have done the trick. Can anyone please help?

thanks

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Answer (score 1):

To use your own ObjectMapper, you would need to implement EntityMapper that allows an ObjectMapper to be injected,

```
  @Bean
  @Autowired
  public EntityMapper mapper(ObjectMapper objectMapper) {
    return new ConfigurableEntityMapper(objectMapper);
  }
```

then create the template with

```
  @Bean
  public ElasticsearchOperations elasticsearchTemplate(Client client, EntityMapper mapper) {
    return new ElasticsearchTemplate(client, mapper);
  }
```

See example here: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-elasticsearch/wiki/Custom-ObjectMapper